# Should a reference to an observable be kept or will the subscription alone do

Tags: angular, garbage-collection, observable, rxjs5, subscription

I recently came across this (Angular) code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscriptions.add(
    this.createSomeObservable()
      .subscribe(v => console.log('v=', v))
  );
}
```

Is this safe or should the returned observable from `this.createSomeObservable()` be stored as a member on the class to prevent being garbage collected?

The `this.createSomeObservable()` was actually a select from an ngrx store if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Until you do not unsubscribe to the observable, the data will not be garbage collected. However, if it is an HTTP observable we are discussing about, it gets unsubscribed after a single response. So you might have to deal with garbage collection in that case. Else until you unsubscribe, garbage collection shouldn't affect you in any way.
Hope that helps!!

Comment: The question is whether or not the reference to the observable needs to be stored to prevent it from being garbage collected after ngOnInit has finished.

Comment: Do you know where the observable reference is held then? Is it inside the returned subscription object? Is it documented somewhere that this is safe to do?

Answer (score -1):

If angular is destroying component/directive with `ngOnDestroy()` there can be possible memory leaks due to the situation, when `observable` wasn't unsubscribed. So we have to focus more on proper **subscribing** and **unsubscribing** rather than preserving observables. It's way better solution.

You want to keep your `observable` as long as possible I assume, so the simplest way would be moving your observable with `subscribe()` to some kind of a injectable provider `service`. You [can check some docs about services here.](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) Unfortunately it will live long and prosper until You properly unsubscribe it(destroy it) - the memory leak risk is still possible.

The thing You can do is to properly unsubscribe when You are done with using your observable. There are few possible solutions but the one I'll recommend is using `async pipe`. It moves `unsubscribe` problem to angular and like no one else it knows when to unsubscribe. There are also other methods like `takeUntil()` but You can have some reasearch yourself i.e. [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html).

If You really want to focus on values not on observables itself - You can just pass them from parent to child and the opposite way. [Here's some reading about component interactions](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

TLDR; Do not preserve observables - focus on proper subscribing and unsubscribing to them when needed.

**EDIT**: I did misunderstand OP question - so I'll give and example how to store our values from subscribe (which are of type observable) in component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-user-settings',
    templateUrl: './user-settings.component.html'
})
export class UserSettingsComponent {

   userSettings$: Observable<UserSettings>;
   permissions$: Observable<UserSettingsPermissions>;

constructor(private store: Store<fromUserSettings.State>) {
    this.UserSettings$ = store.select(fromUserSettings.getUserSettings);
    this.permissions$ = store.select(fromUserSettings.getPermissions);
}

onSaveSettings(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new userSettings.PostUserSettings(formGroup));
 }
}
```

I'm assigning my observables to local variables that are package available(to use them in HTML). So yes, if You need to use them around your component You can store them in some variables. This way observables taken from store should be available as long as component is not destroyed. Hope that can brighten up my answer.

PS. I'm using ngrx store here so it might be helpful.

Comment: I'm not asking about memory leaks because of not unsubscribing. I'm asking about the necessity of storing the reference to the observable returned from createSomeObservable().

Comment: @Halt I did some edit to show You how I preserve values from observables in my `Component`. I hope it will help You up a little and if not - leave a comment so I'll try to explain it in some more complex way - cheers

Comment: Thx, I understand how I can store them but I wonder if it is needed or not. Will the garbage collector get them if I don't store the reference or is the observable somehow held by the subscription internally?